# How to generate resource entry of string type ID?

Tags: windows, winapi, embedded-resource, rc

I have a .rc file with the following entry:

```
01111 my_res { "string 1" }
01113 my_res { "string 2" }
01119 my_res { "string 3" }
```

When I compile this .rc file with rc.exe, the resource entry id become `1111`, `1113` and `1119` respectively.

Apparently, the resource compiler treated the ID as numerics.

My first impression was the `.res` files can't store numeric as string type.  But when use a resource editor (e.g.: `XNResourceEditor.exe` to change the resource ID `1111` to `01111` and it stored as `01111`.  This shows that the resource id may store numeric as string type.

Is there a way to compile numeric resource id as string type?

Comment: Can you show you an entire resource script. We are missing a lot of context here. For instance, we don't know what `my_res` is. Obviously don't show your entire script, cut it down first.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That is my cut down version of rc file.  I have only one type of resource.

Comment: It doesn't compile when I use brcc32. I assume that resource compiler since the question is tagged delphi. If you mean to use rc, then the delphi tag is wrongly applied.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Go to `Project | Options` and change the resource compiler to `Windows SDK Resource Compiler`.  Don't use `Borland Resource Compiler (brcc32.exe)`, it will show errors.

Comment: I've re-tagged the question. It's not a Delphi question, it's a question about the MS resource compiler RC.

Comment: @sashaolm Thanks for adding that tag, rc.exe, but that's a tag with only two questions. That tag should be removed. A better tag is rc.

Comment: Out of interest, did you try putting the IDs in quotes?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I have tried single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`), slash (`/` and `\\`) and none of that works.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang You should avoid the phrase "none of that works". You can put the ID in quotes. But the quotes appear in the id text when you compile the resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource compiler RC does not have any syntax that allows you to escape an integer ID so that it is treated as text.

The documentation says:

> Unique name or a 16-bit unsigned integer that identifies the resource.

The resource compiler attempts to interpret the ID as an integer. If it can do so then the ID is interpreted as an integer, otherwise it is interpreted as a string. If the integer exceeds the bounds of a 16 bit integer, then its value and `0xffff` is used.

This is a limitation of the resource compiler. The resource format supports text IDs that only contain digits. If it is crucial for you to produce such resources then I think you would need to either:

1. Find a resource compiler that does allow numbers to be escaped as text, or
2. Write your own basic resource compiler to perform the task.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far.  I found no other solution by using current tools available.